# Reference does not work for me

Tags: texmaker

I dont know what is wrong, but reference wont work for me. Can someone help.

[image]

Comment: You need to run `bibtex`. If I'm not wrong, press `F11` (or check some menu). Then compile twice again.

Comment: Okay now I got a page called references, but still nothing

Comment: See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764) for a general discussion on why you're receiving undefined references/citations. I assume it would also be helpful to view [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/5764) to get a handle on configuring your editor to work with external processes (including BibTeX).

Comment: Drop the `.bib` extension from `\bibliography`.

Comment: Your code is fine. It is working. You can check on sharelatex
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/549873ebe6f6925860adcc5a Problems may be from system configuration. On which system are you working? Linux or windows? Miktex ot texlive?

Comment: How can the OP's code said to be fine if at least one syntax error (use of `.bib` in the argument of `\bibliography`) is present?

Comment: After running BibTeX, did you run LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes? Have you looked at the log files (extension `.log` and `.blg`) to check if they contain error and/or warning messages related to the bibliography?

Comment: Mico is correct. I am compiling on windows with Miktex, then I .bib extension must be removed. But, This code is working as it is with out any error on Share Latex. May they have some mechanism behind this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) has a process in place to compile a document with BibTeX or biber if necessary (since it's an online "cover all bases" environment), so it would be difficult to analyse the problem using that interface.

Answer (score 3):

The line 5:

```
\bibliography{litteratur.bib}
```

should be changed to **(.bib removed)**:

```
\bibliography{litteratur}
```

to make it work ;)